# Run 2 tasks in parallel and cancel the 2nd task if the first completes .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

If have 2 methods I want to run in parallel on different threads, let's call them Task1 and Task2. If Task2 completes before Task1 then I want the results of both combined into a list. If Task1 completes and Task2 is still running, it should cancel Task2 to avoid further processing. WhenAll doesn't work because it will wait for both tasks. WhenAny doesn't work because it will return if either finish first.

Comment: Create a CancellationTokenSource and pass its Token property to Task2 which would need to check if cancellation was requested by calling the token's ThrowIfCancellationRequested method at certain points. At the end of Task1 call the Cancel method of the CancellationTokenSource to request cancellation of Task2. Use WhenAll – when Task2 gets cancelled and you await the WhenAll result task it would throw a OperationCancelledException which is expected behavior so you would just need to catch it.

Comment: I think that is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well I originally did have code. Then I posted the code as an answer cause no one answered the question. Then the mod told me to put my code in the question. I can't win with this site.

Comment: @BradFiresheets That wasn't a moderator, it was just a regular user.  The main problem was that you posted an answer, but didn't say that you were answering the question, but rather indicating that it was an updated, but still incomplete, solution.  *That* should be an edit to the question.  If you have an answer, and don't have a question any more, *then* it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Yes it was an answer to my own question. I don't think you can see the deleted answer (I can, it's colored red)

Comment: @BradFiresheets I have enough rep to see deleted answers, hence why I knew the comment didn't come from a moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;
    var rates = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        var p44Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetP44Rates(token), token);

        var mgRates = await GetMGRates();

        rates.AddRange(mgRates);

        if (p44Task.IsCompleted && p44Task.Result.IsCompleted)
        {
            rates.AddRange(p44Task.Result.Result);
        }
        else
        {
            // Cancel the p44 task
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    foreach (var rate in rates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rate);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}

private static async Task<List<string>> GetMGRates(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var rates = new List<string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rates.Add($"MG: {i}");
        Console.WriteLine($"MG inside {i}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }


    return rates;
}

private static async Task<List<string>> GetP44Rates(CancellationToken ct)
{
    var rates = new List<string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        rates.Add($"P44: {i}");
        Console.WriteLine($"P44: {i}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bye from p44.");
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to quit.");

            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }

    return rates;
}
```