# Let Task.WhenAny return when one specific task ends

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

How can i run 2 tasks in parallel and get notified when one specific task ends (in my case the first task in the list)

Currently i am using this code:

```
await Task.WhenAny(A.Play(cancel), B.Play(cancel));
```

the code should return when A.Play(cancel) ends but not when b.Play(cancel) ends.

WhenAny does not work because it could happen that B ends before A.
WhenAll does not work because it could be that B is an endless Task.

Comment: Can you just `await A.Play(cancel)`?

Comment: no, both tasks need to run in parallel, if i use await A.play(); await B.Play() they would run in sequential order

Comment: oh, you mean simply not await B, just await A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run 2 tasks in parallel and cancel the 2nd task if the first completes .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380819/run-2-tasks-in-parallel-and-cancel-the-2nd-task-if-the-first-completes-net)

Comment: I am baffled by this question. Isn't this just a case where you `await A` and don't `await B`? Why do you even need `WhenAny()`? Await the task you want to wait for and don't await the task you don't want to wait for--- why is it more complicated than that?

Comment: @JohnWu He wants that block of code to only continue when one or the other is completed, and if A happens to complete before B he wants something additional to happen (cancel B, perhaps).  So if B finishes first, great continue running the block. If A finishes first, cancel B then continue. Not sure why so many baffled by this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap 'A.Play' in a new task method that does whatever you want after 'A.Play' completes.

```
async Task CallingMethod()
{
    await Task.WhenAny(WrapperA(), B.Play(cancel));
}

async Task WrapperA()
{
    await A.Play(cancel)
    // Here you can fire an event or set the cancellation token
    // Or whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: Note that you could also do this with `A.Play(cancel).ContinueWith(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you want. The tasks will run in parallel, but you await aTask first, so it returns only when aTask returns. You can then include seperate logic to await bTask.

```
Task aTask = A.Play(cancel);
Task bTask = B.Play(cancel);

// will return only when A is complete. 
await aTask;

// await bTask seperately.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
B.Play()
```

without `await` to run `B` without waiting for it to end and then do

```
await A.Play()
```

Comment: I'm assuming he wants to cancel B if A finishes first, but otherwise wants to wait until they both finish.

Comment: But what if B.play throws an exception?